Special Character csv in ODI12c
I need your support. I'm trying to load a csv file in ANSI format in ODI, but when it loads ODI can't read special characters like apostrophe or accents. If I try to open the file in notepad I see the special characters correctly. I tried to convert the file to UFT-8 but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?
Also the file has all the lines like this "xxxx;yyy" how do I manage the quotes?
Hi all, I need your support.

for example when I open the file in notepad in ANSI o UFT8 format i see these rows ("00.14;Iniezione o infusione di antibiotici della classe dell'oxazolidinone") but when i upload the file in ODI i see this "00.14;Iniezione o infusione di antibiotici della classe dellâ€™oxazolidinone" WHY? in addition i aspect that the data visualizations is without " and with '          00.14;Iniezione o infusione di antibiotici della classe dell'oxazolidinone
